# Alfresco. Копирование документов в реестры Alvex, с кастомными значениями

Tags: javascript

В моей Alfresco есть дополнительный модуль Alvex, который предоставляет функцию реестров документов.
Сейчас стоит задача перенести документы из одного реестра, в другой, и попутно проставить значения счетчика в одно из полей.
Статья от разработчиков описывает простое копирование документов, но не показывает, как связать разные поля: http://www.ossportal.ru/technologies/alfresco/blogs/780

Мой скрипт выглядит так:

```
// Получаем название сайта с реестрами и контейнер с реестрами, вместо 'office' подставьте название своего сайта
var site = siteService.getSite('chairman');
var cont = site.getContainer('dataLists');

// Указываем, из какого реестра мигрировать документы (srcList) и в какой реестр их мигрировать (dstList), указываем номер реестра в соответствии с выводом в прошлом скрипте (нумерация начинается с 0)
var srcList = cont.children[7];
var dstList = cont.children[1];
i1 = 1;
// Копируем все документы из srcList в dstList
for each(item in srcList.children) {

  // Создаем пустой документ в новом реестре
  var node = dstList.createNode(null, "alvexdtCustom:received");

  // Копируем все ассоциации текущего документа в старом реестре в новый документ
  for (assoc in item.assocs) {
    for each(i in item.assocs[assoc]) {
      node.createAssociation(i, assoc);
    }
  }

  // Копируем все свойства текущего документа в старом реестре в новый документ
  for (prop in item.properties) {
    node.properties[prop] = item.properties[prop];
    if (prop == "alvexdtCustom:serialNumber") {
      node.properties[prop] = i1;
      print(node.properties[prop]);
    }
  }

  //print("i: "+prop);
  i1++;

  // Сохраняем новый документ
  node.save();
}
```

при этом, в условии `if (prop == "alvexdtCustom:serialNumber") {`
пробовал указывать просто `serialNumber`, но в итоге значение в это поле не проставляется.
Конфиг поля, в которое я хочу выглядит так:

```
<aspect name="alvexdtCustom:serialNumber">
    <properties>
        <property name="alvexdtCustom:serialNumber">
            <title>П\Н</title>
            <type>d:long</type>
            <index enabled="true">
                <atomic>true</atomic>
                <stored>true</stored> 
                <tokenised>both</tokenised>
            </index>
        </property>
    </properties>
</aspect>
```

Возможно у кого-либо есть идеи, как вставить в поле значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас if находится в цикле копирования свойств. А в старом реестре не было такого свойства вообще, так что не удивительно, что скрипт ни разу не заходит в if.

Замените

```
for (prop in item.properties) {
  node.properties[prop] = item.properties[prop];
  if (prop == "alvexdtCustom:serialNumber") {
    node.properties[prop] = i1;
    print(node.properties[prop]);
  }
}
```

на

```
for (prop in item.properties) {
  node.properties[prop] = item.properties[prop];
}
node.properties["alvexdtCustom:serialNumber"] = i1;
```

Comment: Тысяча благодарностей, Вы меня спасли!
И отдельное большое спасибо что продолжаете оказывать поддержу даже после закрытия Oss Portal`a!

Comment: Но все равно, номера в перемешку получились(
А можно srcList предварительно отсортировать по дате регистрации?

Comment: Как-нибудь так: http://stackoverflow.com/a/890829/2377109

Answer (score 0):

А можно чуть больше деталей? Это просто счетчик, который работает в рамках же скрипта миграции, который проставляет значения 1, 2, 3 итд в поле alvexdtCustom:serialNumber?

Второй вопрос: поля "Номер документа" недостаточно? Он вроде делает ровно это же.

Comment: Проблема в том, что номер документа, это стринг "1\ДКТ", или что то подобное, и отсортировать потом все это дело просто не возможно, после 1000 все вообще сбивается. Идея в том, чтоб добавить поле типа лонг, и сортировать по нему. В скрипте я пробовал в поле alvexdtCustom:serialNumber вставить значение счетчика i1, но у меня почему-то никак не получается, это поле постоянно оказывается пустое. В итоге, я расчитывал получить П\Н 1000 Номер "1000" П\Н 1001 Номер "1000\ДКТ"